# Openshift HAproxy sticky session issue

Tags: openshift, load-balancing, haproxy

I have a deployment with 2 pods of a web application. The web application requires a logon and maintains a session. 
After i kill the first pod i am automatically redirected to the logon page of the second pod, but when the first pod is loaded again i am redirected back to it.
I have tried to use the HAproxy "balance source" algorithm and coockies.
Any idea why doesn't it stay with the second pod?

Comment: In this case, you should have a session database that all instances of your application use. Keeping a session database in memory when you have multiple instances is never reliable when have multiple processes. What language/framework are you using?

Comment: For the client side we use an IBM tool called jazz which is not an open source. My main question is why HAproxy redirects the connection back to the first pod when it goes up and not stays with the second pod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`balance source` uses a hashing algorithm that changes the workload distribution every time the number of available backends changes, because that is what it's designed to do.  If you had more than 2 backends, you would also find that taking down any one backend will cause some traffic that wasn't even hitting the impacted backend to shift to another, because of this redistribution.

> If the hash result changes due to the number of running servers changing, many clients will be directed to a different server.
>
> http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4-balance

For an explanation of why you didn't see the expected behavior when using cookies instead of `balance source`, we'd need to see your configuration.

Comment: Thank you! So what is the correct algorithm I should have used instead of balance source in my use case?

Comment: See [`cookie`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4-cookie).  The `balance` algorithm isn't all that critical, since that is only used for selecting a backend when the client has no existing affinity established.